# vue-router – check if child of specific subroute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Checked similar questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find a working solution.

I want to check if a subroute is the child of a specific route to display a container (or not).

The following doesn't work unfortunately:

```
<div v-if="this.$route.matched.some(route => route.path === '/projects')">
   etc.
</div>
```

I'm trying to display the `div` container on `www.example.com/projects` AND on `www.example.com/projects/foo`

I also tried omitting the `this`.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Do you use Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<div v-if="this.$route.matched.some(route => route.path.includes('/projects'))">
   etc.
</div>
```

includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate so `www.example.com/projects/foo` and  `www.example.com/projects` return true

Answer (score 1):

If I need to hide some div in one of the paths I am using `this.$route.path` property.

```html
<div v-if="this.$route.path === '/projects'">
  Display only on views witch route is /projects
</div>
```

If you want to hide div in all paths which contains '/projects' you can make it in this way.

```html
<div v-if="this.$route.path.indexOf('/projects') >= 0">
  Display only on views which contains /projects
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked as well as the other answers!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to check on the name of the route

```
['route1', 'subroute1'].indexOf($route.name) >= 0
```